# Return a plain xml (no child elements) with Web Api

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

how could I return a very simple xml that is composed by its root element only ? something like:
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <myelement> somevalue </myelement>`

The issue is that there are no child elements so I don't know what type of POCO class I should write to get that output. 
What I've been trying is to return a string but I end up with

```
<string>somevalue</string>
```

I'm new to the WebApi so any suggestion will be very appreciated !

Comment: You want to customize Xml sent from Web Api?

Comment: Hi, yes I was looking for a simpler way to return a custom xml like the one on the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is not the best solution but it is working for now:

```
public class MyCustomFormatter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = actionExecutedContext.Response;
        var contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType;
        var oldContents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        oldContents = oldContents.Replace("string", "myelement");
        response.Content = new StringContent("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + oldContents);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = contentType;
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = response.Content;
    }
}
```